# Prolog - Appending to an existing file term list

Tags: list, prolog

I have a term contained in a file:

```
fruit(apple, []).
```

I'm trying to write input to it, so that each set of information will be appending to the empty list as a list to compose a list of lists, in a manner like:

```
fruit(apple, [[30, 'fresh'], [10, 'old'], ... ]).
```

So far I only know how to write a separate term:

```
add_fruit(File, Type, Price, State) :-
   open(File, append, Stream),
   writeq(Stream, fruit(Type, [Price, State])),
   write(Stream, '.'),
   nl(Stream), nl(Stream),
   close(Stream).
```

This will produce a term such as:

```
fruit(apple, [20, 'some state']).
```

However I don't want to have to create a new term every time I use the `add_fruit` predicate, rather I want to append a list containing `Price` and `State` to the appropriate fruit type term.

Would it be possible to extend the predicate so that it will write to the existing term, rather than create a new one?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You probably want to `consult` the file, not `open` it, use `retract` and `assert` to manipulate your data while your program is running, then write the data back to the file at some convenient point later on.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up concepts here a bit. First off, if you have a Prolog file, say "food.pl" with the contents:

```
fruit(apple, []).
```

then `fruit/2` is not exactly a term, but rather the *fact* `fruit/2` (predicate without a body, only with a head) which maps the atom `apple` (first argument) to the empty list (the second argument).

What you can do now is consult the file, which will put the fact in the database.

Another thing: are you sure you need to keep appending to the list in the second argument? Why not normalize your database, and have, for example:

```
fruit(apple, price_state(30, fresh)).
fruit(apple, price_state(10, old)).
% etc
```

Here, you now have a table, `fruit`, with two columns. The first is the name of the fruit, the second is a *term* `price_state/2` with the price as the first argument and the state as the second. You could have just as well said:

```
fruit_price_state(apple, 30, fresh).
fruit_price_state(apple, 10, old).
% etc
```

if you indeed want your table to map the fruit to a state and a price. You can now add and remove rows from the table using `assertz` and `retract`. In other words, design your database as you would design a relational database, using facts as tables. This approach translates directly to Prolog. You can then query the database, for example, to give you the combination of price and state for apples:

```
?- bagof(price_state(P, S), fruit(apple, P, S), PSs).
```

This will put a list of `price_state/2` in `PSs`, or fail, if you don't have apples in your database (you could use `findall/3` if you prefer to get an empty list instead, but then you would have to deal with that empty list in any predicate that takes `PSs`).

One way to deal with persistence, that is, load facts to the database, add/remove rows, and then save the updated database back to the same file is using Edinburgh-style I/O with `see`, `tell`, `told` etc.

If you are using SWI-Prolog, you also have the option of using [`library(persistency)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/persistency.pl). See the link for a working minimal example.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I need to keep appending to the list in the second argument so I don't clutter the knowledge base with facts. I'm a little confused with how you're using `bagof `in your example. I tried normalizing the database (just to give it a test) as you've presented as an example, and then querying the knowledge base, however an error was returned as `fruit` only contains two arguments (`apple` and `price_state`).